# How do I get a random index of a table in Lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I get a random question from `qus`, a table of four questions?

```
-- qus = table of questions
for i = 1 , 4 do
    qus = {}
    qus[i] = "what is your name?"
    qus[i] = "how old are you?"
    qus[i] = "where are you living?"
    qus[i] = "what are you doing?"

    local label = display.newText(qus[i],160,100)
end
print(qus[i])

-- Prints:
-- what are you doing
-- what are you doing
-- what are you doing
-- what are you doing
```

I tried this:

```
qus[1] = "what is your name?"
qus[2] = "how old are you?"
qus[3] = "where are you living?"
qus[4] = "what are you doing?"

label = all qus shows
```

Thank you for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use math.random() function:

```
local qus = {}

qus[1] = "what is your name?"
qus[2] = "how old are you?"
qus[3] = "where are you living?"
qus[4] = "what are you doing?"

math.randomseed(os.time ()) -- init generator

local index = math.random(#qus)   -- between 1 and  4 (size of table)
print(qus[index])
```

Comment: Just clarification: `math.randomseed(os.time ()) -- init generator` should be called once on app start. No need to call it before each `math.random` call